# How do I create a helper method which accepts unknown class types and return the correct object

Tags: java, ormlite

I have the following line of code for ORMLITE to create a dao (Data access object). I am trying to avoid repeating myself for ALL entities by writing the same statement for different database tables/entities.

```
Dao<Entity, String> entityDao = DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource,Entity.class);
```

How can i create a method which accepts ANY Entity that i have and return the correct entityDao object.

Such that I can combine the logic

```
Dao<UserEntity, String> userEntityDao = DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource,UserEntity.class);
```

and

```
Dao<AccountEntity, String> accountEntityDao = DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource,AccountEntity.class);
```

I have tried the following method:

```
  private Dao<?, String> createDAO(Class<?> dataClass) throws SQLException{
        // instantiate the dao
        return DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, dataClass);
    }
```

But unfortunately i am getting the following error:

> ```
> incompatible types: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
>     inferred: Dao<CAP#1,?>
>     upper bound(s): Dao<CAP#1,?>,Dao<?,String>
>   where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
>     CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a generic type parameter `T` to your `createDAO` method:

```
private <T> Dao<T, String> createDAO(Class<T> dataClass) throws SQLException {
    return DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, dataClass);
}
```

If you look at the definition of [`DaoManager.createDao`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/DaoManager.html#createDao(com.j256.ormlite.support.ConnectionSource%2C%20java.lang.Class)), you will see that it is defined in a similar, albeit more complex, way:

```
public static <D extends Dao<T,?>,T> D createDao(ConnectionSource connectionSource,
                                                 Class<T> clazz) throws SQLException
```